# Windows XP VPN Server with Static IP in a VM

Tags: networking, windows-xp, virtual-machine, vpn

My network is in a small business network environment. 1 48 port switch, business grade modem, 30+ computers. Lets say I want to VPN to one of our static IP addresses. These computers all use the external IP (example) 111.111.111.50. I created a Windows XP virtual machine on one of these computers using VMWare Workstation and set it on a static external IP 111.111.111.48 in the VM. I went to Google and confirmed it is working with this new external IP address (searched for What Is My IP).

Then, I setup an "Incoming Connection" in the network connections panel in the Windows XP VM so I could VPN to this external IP address from outside the network. However, my Android phone keeps saying "Disconnected" when it tries to connect. I'm not sure how to see an error log for this, but I have the firewall disabled on the VM.

What am I missing? Is this even a possible thing to do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to find out why the connection fails,

1. incoming VPN connections are not arriving your VM,
2. the Android VPN client is configured with wrong password/certificate.

The best way is to install Wireshark in the VM, and trace network data while you try to connect with Android. In this way you can see whether IP packets trying to establish VPN arrive at the VM and how the VM answers.